# Points on a cubic curve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

Regarding proof of a converse of a cubic equation's property:

A curve passes through 3 collinear points (A, C and E) on x - axis.  Points B and D are respectively midpoints of CA and CE. If the tangent  at intersection  point of perpendicular at B with curve goes through E and tangent that of  D  through A, show that the curve is a polynomial of third degree with roots at A, C and E.

EDIT1:

Alternatively stated: If abscissas (roots) at A, C and E are a,b and c are respectively any three given ascending numbers satisfying following functional differential relations, then show that function f is a cubic function.

$ \frac {f((a+b)/2)} {f^{'}((a+b)/2)} = (a + b)/2 - c $

$ \frac {f((b+c)/2)} {f^{'}((b+c)/2)} = (b+c)/2 -a $

EDIT2:Typo related error at RHS corrected.

Comment: Question:  if the curve passes through $5$ points on the $x$-axis, musn't it be of degree at least $5$?

Comment: @Robert Lewis: Thanks,edited it.